# What is the computational complexity for regular languages?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, automata

Is it the case that set membership problem for all regular languages can be solved in the time complexity of order $O(n)$ ? And Can we say that all set membership problems that can be solved in $O(n)$ are regular, where n is the input set?

My approach: We can construct a DFA for the regular language, then in that case the time complexity will be of order $O(n)$, but it does not prove that all set membership problems that run in $O(n)$ will be regular so how should we proceed with this part of the proof.

Comment: Yes: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48213/if-set-membership-problem-can-be-solved-for-a-particular-language-does-this-impl

Comment: I don't see a formal proof of the statement in the link that you have provided?

Comment: Can we say that all set membership problems that can be solved in $O(n)$ are regular?

Comment: What is $n$? It matters how the problem is given - what description of the regular language is your algorithm given?

Comment: n is the size of the input set. I don't understand what you mean by the description.

Comment: What is the "input set"?

Comment: "Input set" is the input for the algorithm for which the set membership can be solved $O(n)$.

Comment: What is the input of the algoritm?

Comment: I just meant to ask, that can all set membership problems that can be solved in O(n) are regular? If you are going to construct a dfa for the same then it will take n states that proves that it to be $O(n)$ is wrong. And I think that's want you want n to be. If you know the formal proof for it please do answer, Please Help! Don't downvote

Comment: @MishaLavrov , the answers in the link you have provided have proved it for  $\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)$ and not for $O(n)$. If it's possible then please provide a link to any research paper.

Comment: If the language accepted by any $o(n\log n)$ machine is regular, then certainly the language accepted by any $O(n)$ machine is regular.